# Storekit - Production Environment Only - do SKProduct localizedTitle and localizedDescription depend only on iTunes Store location as in the Sandbox?

Tags: localization, storekit, skproduct

As explained in [Technical Note TN2413](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-LOCALIZATION-MY_IN_APP_PURCHASE_HAS_LOCALIZED_INFORMATION_FOR_VARIOUS_LANGUAGES_ON_ITUNES_CONNECT__HOWEVER__THE_LOCALIZEDDESCRIPTION_AND_LOCALIZEDTITLE_PROPERTIES_ALWAYS_RETURN_INFORMATION_IN_ENGLISH_EVEN_THOUGH_MY_TEST_DEVICE_LANGUAGE_IS_NOT_SET_TO_ENGLISH) regarding the testing of IAP localizations:

> localizedDescription and localizedTitle return localized information
>   whose language is based on the current iTunes Store rather than the
>   current device language setting. For instance, if your in-app purchase
>   is localized for German in iTunes Connect and you are logged with an
>   English test user account, then localizedDescription and
>   localizedTitle will return information localized in English. To have
>   localizedDescription and localizedTitle return information localized
>   in German, login with a German test user account on your test device.

All well and good, and verified in the Sandbox.

What I am having trouble confirming is whether the same is true of the production store: does the language of localizedTitle and localizedDescription depend solely on the iTunes store location, or is it based on [NSLocale preferredLanguages] or the current localeIdentifier?

On the one hand, it would make sense for the production store to behave like the test store, but on the other hand this seems like a strange choice as ultimately it makes more sense for the user's language preferences to dictate what localization they are served.

For example, a German user who prefers to speak German may live in France and use the French App Store.

For various reasons this is difficult to verify personally, and I can find no concrete documentation regarding this.  Can anyone confirm the way this works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Localization is determined based off of the users storefront along with their device settings. It is possible that a Romanian user would see the English description even while being in the Romanian storefront (but the price would be in Romanian currency).

There are several use cases that fit into this (for example users that are traveling, or live in a region different from their native language).

So to answer your question, it is determined by both language preference AND storefront (which can be different than the users actual location).

Comment: I understand that localization as a whole will depend on both iTunes Store Location and device settings. But what I was specifically interested in is whether the language used for SKProduct localizedDescription and localizedTitle is determined by the iTunes Store Location OR by device settings.  Your answer implies that these specific fields are localized solely according to the device settings (Romanian Store front, English text), however if I switch my device language to German and log on to the UK App Store - everything is still in English. One might expect the same for SKProduct fields.